# SVG doesn't fit into corner correctly

Tags: html, css, svg

I am relatively new to HTML and CSS, and I used InVision Studio to make an SVG that I want to go into the corner of my page for decorative effect. I'm not looking for anything to be perfectly designed, as this is mostly just for learning purposes, but I want this SVG shape to fit in the bottom right corner as it does in InVision.

I am using the same screen size for both, but there is a small bit of the background body gradient that is getting by on the right and bottom of the SVG. How do I get it to fit properly + do you have any general tips for better coding?

Screenshot of my project so far, with the issue on the right and bottom of the SVG shape:

[image]

Since I am using local files, I attached an image of my issue, along with snippets of my code so you can read what I have.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Side bar */

.avatar {
  background-image: url(../images/plant.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-position: top center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 40px 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar {
  width: 280px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #49596A;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #637486;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
  color: rgba(80, 215, 108, 0.8);
}

/* Banner */

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ebd2d2, #ec9e9e, #fd7575);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
}

.banner {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #2F5061;
  font-size: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background: url(../images/stupidsquiggle.svg) no-repeat bottom right;
}

.banner p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #576B75;
  /* background: url(../images/stupidsquiggle.svg) no-repeat bottom right; */
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="navbox">
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="banner">
    <h1>My name is Aidan.</h1>
    <p>I'm a designer, developer, and artist who likes to use my skills to create a more interactive world.</p>
  </div>


<!--SVG CODE STARTS HERE

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1034.705" height="628.205" viewBox="0 0 1034.705 628.205">
  <defs>
<path id="path-1" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.35231505 625.85231505s80.64137988-134.84412933 179-158.5c110.36073391-26.54245499 332.85909199 8.44965018 482.71594596-45.72417312 94.30372859-34.09115695 139.40900564-133.83540883 173.78405404-211.27582688 89-200.5 194.5-208 194.5-208v623.5h-1030z"/>
  </defs>
  <g>
<use fill="rgb(87,107,117)" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
<use fill-opacity="0" stroke="rgb(128,128,128)" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="1" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
  </g>
</svg>

SVG CODE ENDS HERE -->

</body>
```

Comment: Your question: ***SVG doesn't fit into corner correctly***. . . You have the problem with SVG and you have not included it. . . How will we test!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal , This may sound a bit dull but... How would I go about getting the code for this SVG? As of now it's in my files similar to a photo.

Comment: Drag the SVG in your code editor. Copy the code and add it to the question! 

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Sorry about the delay! I have added the SVG code into the HTML document at the bottom, and it is commented out so you can do what you need to. Thank you for checking this out for me!

Comment: I suggest you add the gradient+image(svg) as background of the body or HTML tag :) you can set multiple backgrounds, a simple google will sho you how

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
```